# Getting data to stick around for return statment

Tags: jquery, node.js, function, reactjs, webpack

So I have this code to assign data to the vehicles array and the console log is producing the correct result:

```
  circleAlerts = circleAlerts.map(function(assetf,index){
          return(
            assetf.map(function(asset, index){
              var vehiclesT = asset.assetIDs;
              if(!asset.assetIDs){
                vehiclesT = [];
              }
              var y;
              var vehicles = []
              for(y=0; y< vehiclesT.length; y++){
                var url = 'api/assetName/?vid='+vehiclesT[y]+'&id='+id;
                fetch(url, {credentials: 'include', method: 'get'}).then(function(body){
                  return body.text();
                }).then(function(data) {
                  vehicles.push(data);
                  if(y == vehiclesT.length - 1){
                    vehicles = vehicles.map(function(vehiclef, index){
                      return(
                        <li key={index}>{vehiclef}</li>
                      )
                    });
                  }
                  console.log(vehicles);
                });
              }
```

Right after this I have this return statement but the vehicles variable is emtpy unlike the console log it produces:

```
      var ind = index;
      var indHash = "#" + ind;
      var indExtra = ind + "ex";
      maps.push(indExtra);
      return(
        <li key={ind}>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-info alarmListButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={indHash}>{asset.name}</button>
          <div id={ind} className="collapse alarmHolder">
            <Map ref={indExtra} style={mapStyles} center={asset.point.coordinates} zoom={7}>
            <TileLayer
            url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            </Map>
            <div className="alertListAssets"><ul>{vehicles}</ul></div>
          </div>
        </li>
      )
    })
  )
});
```

How can I have the values I see in the console stick around for the return statement so I can show them to the user?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code, your approach is not following the React way of thinking. There are many things to improve in here, but I will only list a couple.

First and most importantly, you need to remove the fetch from that loop, otherwise you will make so many calls to the server. The browser can only send a limited number of requests at the time, therefore your app will be super slow. If possible (meaning you can update the API), try to get all the records at once, send all the IDs you need in the params.

Next, you want to keep the data in the state. Initially it will be an empty array but when the API responds, you should update the state with the result.

Finally, in the render method you will get the data from the state and use it to render the list. *Anytime the state/props get updated, the render method automatically runs for you*.

```
class YourAwesomeComponent extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    vehicles: [], // Keep data in the state
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData(); // Call the API!
  }

  loadData() {
    const url = `api/assetName/?vid=${vehiclesT.join(',')}&id=${id}`;

    fetch(url, { credentials: 'include', method: 'get' })
      .then(body => body.text())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ vehicles: data }); // Set the result from API
      });      
  }

  render() {
    const { vehicles } = this.state; // Get the data from the state
    var ind = index;
    var indHash = "#" + ind;
    var indExtra = ind + "ex";
    maps.push(indExtra);

    return(
    <li key={ind}>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info alarmListButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={indHash}>{asset.name}</button>
      <div id={ind} className="collapse alarmHolder">
        <Map ref={indExtra} style={mapStyles} center={asset.point.coordinates} zoom={7}>
        <TileLayer
        url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        </Map>
        <div className="alertListAssets">
          <ul>
          {
            vehicles.map(vehicle => 
              <li key={vehicle.id}>{vehicle.name}</li>
            )
          }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
  }
}
```

There are soooo many things to improve in here, but you can start with this. I hope this is just a learning project and not something you are planing to release on the wild :)

*PS: Im assuming you can use ES6*